# What is the limit I can shift a binary number?

Tags: assembly, mips

For an assignment we are supposed to shift over a 32 bit binary number by 44, does this mean the most significant places become irrelevant? Meaning, do I only care about the 32 bits to closest to the least significant place? For example:

```
 $t0 = 0xBBBBBBBB
 #10111011101110111011101110111011
 sll  $t2,  $t0,  44
```

Comment: Yep. Since 32 bits can store, well, only 32 bits. The rest is truncated (basically this is a multiplication modulo `2 << 31 - 1` operation).

Comment: okay and because it doesn't wrap around, shifting $t0 by 44, results in 0x00000000?

Comment: Yes, it does result in 0.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a typo?  MIPS can only encode 5 bits worth of shift in the `sll` instruction.

Comment: @CarlNorum Now that's what was strange. I ain't no MIPS expert, but 44 is not quite a 5-bit number.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. It's probably why I'm baffled with this question too.

Comment: I don't have a sim handy if I'd try.  Update tomorrow, perhaps.

Comment: Wow.  Autocorrect got me there.  You get the point, I'm sure.

Comment: OK, I just tried it out.  Answer forthcoming.

Comment: @H2CO3 & Jay - the result will almost certainly *not* be 0.  See my answer for a description of what will happen if you assemble that instruction.

Comment: @CarlNorum Correct - +1.

Answer (score 4):

I think your assignment has a typo.  The MIPS `sll` instruction only supports 5 bits worth of shifting.  That is, the field in the instruction encoding is only 5 bits long, so only shift values in [0,31] are legal.  In fact, if I try to assemble this simple program:

```
    .globl f
    .text
f:
    sll $t2, $t0, 44
```

I get a warning from gcc saying:

```
example.s: Assembler messages:
example.s:3: Warning: Improper shift amount (44)
```

Dissassembling the output object shows:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <f>:
   0:   00085300    sll t2,t0,0xc
```

So as you can see, it's only going to *actually* shift by 12.  It's just reduced the shift amount modulo 32.  What this outcome means is that an instruction like the one provided in your assignment simply isn't legal.

Another possible answer to your question is just `0` since left-shifting any number by more than its size is might arguably logically result in a register full of zeroes.  A similar argument works for right shifting, though you will either end up with `0` or `0xffffffff`, depending on sign-extension behaviour and what happened to be in bit 31 when you started.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is confirmed the assignment has a typo. You're probably talking about this problem in: Computer Organization and Design: 
[image]

Where its answer is listed as such: 
[image]

If you assume that sll $t2, $t0, 4, then the answer makes perfect sense.

```
t0 = 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010
t2 = 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 0000
```

After its shifted by 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift by 0 through 31 (inclusive) bit positions on MIPS. Only 5 least significant bits of the shift count are used in shift instructions. Check your MIPS documentation.

If you want to shift by more than 31 positions, you need to break your shift into a series of smaller shifts each of which shifts by 31 or fewer positions.

Comment: Why break up the shift?  You'll just always get `0` anyway.

Comment: @CarlNorum Or -1. Breaking or not breaking depends on what you're doing and how. It may be perfectly fine to make a couple of shifts without doing an extra check and a conditional branch.